# Infinite scrolling with Selenium / Safari / Python - scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to scrape betting websites for a student project but I have trouble scrolling down and displaying the dynamic data of the website. I'm using Selenium, Safari, Python and the traditional ways are not working (ActionChains, execute_script with scroll down...).

I was wondering if someone already ran through such issues and found a solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://www.unibet.fr/sport/football")

# Get around the cookies
l=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"ui-button")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", l)
time.sleep(5)
```

And then i'm stuck. I tried different methods:

- execute_script method with scroll down
- Send space keys to the website / down arrow (working for other website on the same display)
- ActionChains with scroll down to element...

Thanks for your help
Greg

Comment: show code which you tried to use to scroll it.

Comment: some pages may need to scroll only part of screen and get data before next scroll because they remove elements which user can't see.